# gmapsdistance for each row in dataframe, final output

Tags: r, distance

I am new to R, so I am struggling with this and appreciate any help.
I am trying to get the driving distance between two points with lat/lon given. So the dataframe in R, called df3, I am using looks like this

[image]

I use the following code to generate the distance:

```
output<-apply(df3,1,function(x) { gmapsdistance(
  origin =paste0(x[5], "+", x[4]),  
  destination = paste0(x[2], "+", x[1]),  
  mode = "driving", 
  key="my API",  
  shape = "long"  
)})
```

My problem is that in output, I have a list numbered from 1 to n (in each line there is a list with Time, Distance and Status), but I don't know which distance corresponds to which pair of provinces from this list. I tried many ways but it does not seem to work for, can you please tell me where am I doing a mistake or how to get the distance appear with the corresponding provinces in df3?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput()`?

Comment: The elements of the list correspond exactly to the rows of the data frame.  That is how `apply(., 1)` works.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get how can I match them at the end, because the idea is to have the names of provinces and distances in the same dataframe, so how can I do that?

Comment: @jrcalabrese Thank you for your answer, I tried to do that but the dataframe is a little bit long so is there an option where I can only get a part of the dataframe? thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the output of `str(output[[1L]])`?

Comment: @MikaelJagan thank you for your answer. here is the outcome: > str(output[[1L]])
List of 3
 $ Distance: num 1528822
 $ Time    : num 61804
 $ Status  : chr "OK"

Comment: In that case, maybe you want `data.frame(df3, Distance = vapply(output, \`[[\`, 0, "Distance"))`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thank you so much! that solved my problem! but please forgive my ignorance, I just want to make sure that R shouldn't make a mistake in matching the distances with the right pair of provinces right?